# Criar nova instância toda vez ao usar NavigationPage no Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Vamos supor que eu tenhar 3 telas em Xaml e eu uso oMasterDetailPage e NavigationPage para navegar entre essas telas para frente e para trás. Page A -> Page B -> Page C -> ...

Eu uso PushAsync para fazer a navegação. Até aí tudo bem...

Eu implementei isso de duas formas:

**1 -** Crio uma nova instância de cada tela toda vez nas navegações:

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new Views.PageA());
```

**2 -** Crio uma propridade estática (na App View) para cada tela e uso essa propriedade para fazer a navegação:

```
public static Views.PageA PageA 
    {
        get
        {
            if (_pageA == null)
            {
                _pageA = new Views.PageA();
            }

            return _pageA =;
        }
    }


await Navigation.PushAsync(App.PageA);
```

**Tem outra forma de fazer isso? Uso estático ou crio uma nova instância toda vez?**

Minha preocupação é sobre desempenho e uso de memória.

Por favor deixe sua resposta com sua opinião e se puder deixar algum código eu agradeço.

Answer (score 4):

Você deve navegar sempre a Detail. Algo como:

```
var masterDetail = new MasterDetail()
{
    Master = new MasterPage(),
    Detail = new NavigationPage(new DetailPage())
};

MainPage = masterDetail;
```

Para navegar, uma saida seria:

```
var md = App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage;
md.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new NovaPagina());
```

Eu não testei esse código, escrevi de cabeça :p

Porém, uma dica que eu dou é .. use Prism: https://github.com/angelobelchior/prism-xamarin-forms
Muito mais fácil resolver essas questões com ele. Nesse link tem exemplo de navegação com MasterDetail :)

Comment: Angelo, só funcionou dessa maneira:
md.Detail = new NavigationPage(new NovaPagina());

Comment: Show!, o segredo está na Detail com NavigationPage